# php callback function to next page

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, header

I'm using a widget that allow me to execute a callback php function after some events.

I want to have a php function that will allow me to go to the next page using the `GET` method.

From

```
mypage.php?page=1
```

To

```
mypage.php?page=2
```

To

```
mypage.php?page=3
```

and so on...

I tought that something like

```
$page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']); // ==0 if no $_GET['page']
function next_page($page) {
   header('Location: mypage.php?page='.++$page.'');}
```

I know that using header could be tricky. That might be obvious but I'd prefer something reliable and scalable. Maybe if I could execute a `javascript.location` script. Any suggestions?

Comment: `++$page` might need to be `$page++`

Comment: No need for that `.''` at the end of the `header()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$page = 0;
if(isset($_GET['page']))
    $page = intval($_GET['page']);

function next_page($page) {
   $page ++;
   header('Location: mypage.php?page='.$page);
   exit;
}
```

header shouldn't be considered tricky. You just have to make sure no output has been sent to the browser before using it.

Answer (score 1):

Re-assign $page first then append it:

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 0;
```

Then in your function simple call

```
$page++;
header('Location: http://address-to-page/?page=' . $page);
```

Comment: That will return the value of `$page` and *then* increment it, so certainly not http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, edited my answer for completeness.

Comment: You don't need `$page = $page++`: as the increment and decrement operators assign value, simply `$page++;` will suffice.

Comment: And given *that* behaviour, you could put `$page++` straight in the `header()` directive, which is essentially the OP's example.